# Reading from CSV and filtering columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file.

There are a fixed number of columns and an unknown number of rows.

The information I need is always in the same 2 columns but not in the same row.

When column 6 has a 17 character value I also need to get the data from column 0.

This is an example row from the CSV file:

```
E4:DD:EF:1C:00:4F, 2012-10-08 11:29:04, 2012-10-08 11:29:56, -75, 9, 18:35:2C:18:16:ED,
```

Comment: please share some portion of your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Based on your reply to answers below it appears this part of your question "There are a fixed number of columns ..." is false. But it is hard to tell exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file and go through it line by line. Split the line and if element 6 has 17 characters append element 0 to your result array.

```
f = open(file_name, 'r')
res = []
for line in f:
    L = line.split(',')
    If len(L[6])==17:
        res.append(L[0])
```

Now you have a list with all the elements in column 6 of you cvs.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Applying this will give me a list without a split. print L shows the list with all rows like this:

Comment: 'data','data','etc etc (every row between []) So no split done. Element L[6] or any other element coming from the split does not exist.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data? Because Line should be a string and you Need to Split it by your delimiter. Then you get a list of strings for every line

Comment: E4:DD:EF:1C:00:4F, 2012-10-08 11:29:04, 2012-10-08 11:29:56, -75,        9, 18:35:2C:18:16:ED,

Answer (score 0):

You can use **csv** module to read the csv files and you can  provide delimiter/dialect as you need (, or | or tab etc..) while reading the file using csv reader. 
csv reader takes care of providing the row/record with columns as list of values. If you want access the csv record/row as dict then you can use **DictReader** and its methods.

```
import csv
res = []
with open('simple.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        # Index start with 0 so the 6th column will be 5th index
        # Using strip method would trim the empty spaces of column value
        # Check the length of columns is more than 5 to handle uneven columns
        if len(row) > 5 and len(row[5].strip()) == 17:
            res.append(row[0])

# Result with column 0 where column 6 has 17 char length
print res
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I see a little problem. Some columns seems to ad a  ,  as a value if there is no data between ' '   so  'data', 'data1',',','data3' . Needt o get those out first I assume. The above code gvies a  list index out of range on the "if len(row....)

Comment: @BartDecker i am assuming that csv file is having rows with fixed columns (i,e more than 6 columns or 6 columns), if csv file has uneven columns in a row then we need to handle the length of columns check. I updated the code to handle the length condition. Please check!

Comment: Ah this works. Now I receive a list of all items in the first column which have a column 6 with 17 characters, Can I bind the two items together so that the association between the data in column 1 and 6 is not lost?

Comment: @BartDecker you can use string concatenation to combine column 1 and 6 and use it for other calculation as below after the if condition.                                              print row[1] + row[5]

Comment: Much thanks for the help. 1 last question. How would I adapt the code to extend the filter to not only remove the non 17 character long 6th row but also the emtpy 7th row? I tried to add another and statement to the "if", but that doesn't seem to work.